# how do i call jsf template from different xhtml (another bundle) in OSGi

Tags: maven, jsf, templates, osgi, apache-karaf

I want to call xhtml template from another xhtml but this xhtml is in different project(different jar). I'm using OSGi with karaf.

This is my master.xhtml ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:include src="/test/template.xhtml"></ui:include>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This jar hasn't test package. This package is in my another jar. Master jar's folder structure is ;

```
-src
    -main
        -webapp
              -WEB-INF
              -master.xhtml
```

And template jar's folder structure is ;

```
-src
    -main
         -resources
                  -test
                       -template.xhtml
                       -subtemplate.xhtml
         -webapp
               -WEB-INF
```

And the last one my template.xhtml is ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="common-style.css" library="css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <div id="page">

        <div id="header">
            <ui:insert name="header">
                <ui:include src="subtemplate.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

And of course i add to template jar's pom.xml;

```
<Export-Package>
               test;version="1.0",
               *
</Export-Package>
```

And master jar's pom.xml ;

```
<Import-Package>
                .
                .
                .
                .
              test;version="[1.0.0,2.1)",
              *
</Import-Package>
```

But i run the project, i got this error ;

```
/test/template.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

viewId=/master.xhtml
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.io.FileNotFoundException - /test/template.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:280)
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint to the place where the exception is thrown. Check the stacktrace where the URL of the facelet comes from. Find out what you should implement that is capable of looking for files in another bundle (As much as I remember, you can implement a ResourceResolver and configure it in faces-config.xml but it was years ago).