# Export .xhtml templates and use them in another bundle in apache karaf

Tags: jsf, osgi, apache-karaf

Despite there are similar questions, I couldn't find the solution.

I am working with Apache karaf of OSGI Framework. I want to develop
two such bundles that one of them have just template .xhtml files and other one use these templates in its .xhtml pages.

I put my template files in META-INF/resources folder and export it. I import it in manifest of other bundle. But I got

> java.io.FileNotFoundException - /common/commonLayout.xhtml Not Found
>   in ExternalContext as a Resource

when I try to reach the page which uses templates.

I managed to run this structure on an application server(WildFly 8.2.0) by placing .jar file, which includes templates, into META-INF/resources folder. I managed to show .xhtml page with templates. But I can not use this .jar file in OSGI as a seperate bundle.

Comment: You allready asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766005/how-do-i-call-jsf-template-from-different-xhtml-another-bundle-in-osgi. A double post doesn't help any, especially since you already asked at the OPS4j Mailinglist and got some answers to your question. Please use one chanel only